# How to say : I can imagine what you are feeling

Tags: phrase-request

For instance if someone tell me something like "I had a bad day then I am tired and bored etc..."
I would like to answer something which means that "okai I can imagine" meaning okai I can understand what you are feeling now.

In my native language which is French we use to say "I can imagine" but I am not sure about English.

thanks

Comment: I would say "OK, I can imagine that." OK is the standard abbreviation. "that" is not mandatory but is better grammar as it points back to the previous statement.

Comment: "Oh, yeah, I understand." "Oh yeah, I feel you." "Oh yeah, I'm sure." And, "Oh, yeah, I can imagine," is fine :). We say it in English as well.

Comment: Or "Of course, anyone would [be/feel the same if he/she were you]."

Answer (score 2):

> I imagine how you feel.

or:

> I can imagine that.

or (cool, but probably not best English - it was a favorite of a former colleague):

> I feel you.

or even:

> I know, I've been there too.